# Mysql join subtract row until zero, then subtract next row

Tags: mysql

I want to subtract the amount of stock in the **inventory** table, using a join from the **request** table. So stocks in the USA must run out first.

**inventory** table

```
ID | Stock | id_product | origin
1  | 2     | 1          | USA   
2  | 1     | 1          | LONDON
```

**request** table

```
ID | qty | id_product
1  | 1   | 1         
2  | 1   | 1
```

I just want a result like this. With the SELECT JOIN method. Can anyone help?

**result_inventory** table

```
ID | Stock | id_product | origin
1  | 0     | 1          | USA   
2  | 1     | 1          | LONDON
```

Comment: What are the criteria for depleting USA first?

Comment: Calculate cumulative sum over `inventory` then join aggregated `result_inventory`. If aggregated value is above cumulative sum then final value is 0, if it is not below cumulative but less then its lead value then substract else do not change. The solution critically depends on precise MySQL version.

Comment: @Strawberry first criteria is id_inventory

Comment: @Akina i work with mysql 7.4. Can you help me?

Comment: *i work with mysql 7.4* Non-existent version. Show complete `SELECT version();` output.

Comment: @Akina sorry I mean 10.4.17-MariaDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT id, 
                 stock, 
                 id_product, 
                 origin, 
                 SUM(stock) OVER (PARTITION BY id_product ORDER BY id) cum_sum
          FROM inventory ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT id_product, SUM(qty) qty
          FROM request
          GROUP BY id_product )
SELECT id, 
       CASE WHEN cum_sum < qty 
            THEN 0 
            WHEN COALESCE(LAG(cum_sum) OVER (PARTITION BY id_product ORDER BY id), 0) < qty
            THEN cum_sum - qty
            ELSE stock
            END stock,
       id_product, 
       origin
FROM cte1 
JOIN cte2 USING (id_product)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=83491f2f2e5012bc2660bce32403c386